# Does disk space required in compute node when launch instance from block storage?

Tags: storage, ubuntu-16.04, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

Does disk space required in compute node when launch instance from block storage?

My setup is like 1 controller, 3 compute(each 50GB disk) and 1 cinder storage.. I'm lunching instance from cinder volume. While launching instance does it check disk space available in compute node.

Example I have created 100GB bootable volume and launched as instance, But compute node have only 50GB. Does this instance launch successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will.
In the compute nodes only some files with metadata information regarding the instances will be stored, so you will have no problem launching instances of 100GB as long as the backend storage configured in cinder has sufficient space.
Virtlib xml information will be stored in `/var/lib/nova/instances`